# Can we customize/brand the `setup/connect` page used in the Device Authentication OAuth flow?

Tags: community, oauth2

We have a device app using the [Device Authentication OAuth flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_device_flow.htm&type=5) towards Salesforce.

This flow returns an url (`https://domain/setup/connect`) and a user code that the user has to enter into the page at this url, after which Salesforce returns an access token to the app.

If we use a community url as the domain in the first step of the Device Authentication flow, it returns a url that's specific for this community, f.i. `https://mysandboxdomain.cs85.force.com/communityname/setup/connect` (A generic link would be `test.salesforce.com/setup/connect`).

This page allows the user to enter said user code and then redirects to the community login where the user can login using username/password or social. This all works fine and gives the device app an access token through a `services/oauth2/token` url it was polling after successful authentication.

Now my question is, can we brand or customize the `setup/connect` page that redirects to our community? Even just adding a logo and changing some colors would help, but if Visualforce or Lightning can be used it would be great.

PS. 
There seems to be a difference (color mainly) between the community url and the generic test url, which make me suspect there must be something possible:

`https://mysandboxdomain.cs85.force.com/communityname/setup/connect` 
[image: Community specific]

`test.salesforce.com/setup/connect`
[image: Generic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different background color already made me suspect that something would be possible and it indeed is.

You can change the logo, the background color and the footer in the Community Administration settings, under Login and Registration

[image: Settings menu]

The results:

[image]